# Best practice for copying zipped files to a destination directory and uncompress

Tags: java, gzip, file-transfer

I am writing a java program to transfer .gz files from one location to a different location in the same server. There are multiple directories and and every directory has .gz files. The structure is like this -

```
-- dir1

  -- 1.gz

  -- 2.gz 
-- dir1

  -- 1.gz

  -- 2.gz
```

There are around 100 directories and each includes some .gz files. The number of .gz files inside every directory is increasing at a certain period. My approach was to copy the source files to a temp directory, uncompress the files in the temp directory and then move those files to destination. Is this approach reasonable? Is there any best practice I can follow for this type of file transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to uncompress the files at the target destination. Do you want to keep the target as updated as possible ("online operation"), or is this a one-off task, and you do not need to keep on repeating the operation once it is finished? If you are using this as an online operation, then you should be using a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to look for changes. Under a unix-like environment (highly probable, since .gz is mostly used under unix), this uses the `inotify` system call, and is highly efficient.

Is it a problem if you get inconsistent state? That is, if files `dir1/3.gz` and `dir2/3.gz` were updated at the same time, is it a problem if `dir1/3.gz` gets copied over but `dir2/3.gz` does not? You can protect against these data races by

- checking the consistency of the copy before finishing the operation. This would involve denying access until `dir2/3.gz` has been copied and all is consistent; you could, for example, use the WatchService to listen for changes that happen while you are copying. You would then process those changes, and only finish the operation after everything stabilizes: all changes processed and X seconds without changes.
- copying only fully-consistent states (that is, not copying `dir1/3.gz` unless `dir2/3.gz` is getting copied too). You could do this by looking at timestamps, and not copying anything modified in the last X seconds before your program started.

I understand that the reason for uncompressing to a temporary directory before moving to final destination is to avoid inconsistent states. Otherwise, your program would run faster if no moving is required (that is: uncompress directly to the target directory).